# Amount of exactly approximated samples with Padé approximation

Tags: approximation

I've already had some good discussion with Fat32 in [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/55334/self-study-question-about-pad%C3%A9-approximation-and-transfer-functions/55335?noredirect=1#comment111083_55335) yesterday.

Today I'm confused again. The author of **Statistical digital signal processing and modeling** M.h. Hayes and Fat32 both stated that Padé can approximate p+q+1 samples. Then I found this exercise
[image: exercise]

and the solution
[image: solution]

Do I count wrong or are there **5** samples used for the approximation? q+p+1 should be $2+3+1=6$ and therefor 6 perfectly approximated samples. Okay I've calculated it. Due to the periodicity the sixth sample is correct too. But what if the vector would be e.g. 10 at $x[5]$ (sixth sample)?

To solve for the a's I'd then have 3 equations for the vector $[1, a_1, a_2]^T$ which is impossible to solve. Where do I make the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem and its solution is consistent with the Monson Hayes' book that describes Padé approximation.

Your mistake is that you've taken $p=2$ but $q=3$ which is wrong. Correct is $q=2$ and there are 3 unknowns in $b[k]$ , that the problem defines a *second order system* , i.e, $a[k] = [1, a_1, a_2]$ and $b[k] = [b_0, b_1, b_2]$ , according to the book.

Since there are $p+q+1 = 2+2+1 = 5$ (that +1 is for $b_0$) unknown coefficients in the system transfer function $H(z)$, then from its impulse response $h[n],$ only the first 5 samples will match to the data $x[n]$ for $n = 0,1,2,3,4$.

And from the given solution as you can see there are 5 equations for 5 unknowns, of last 2 is used to solve for the unknowns $a_1,a_2$ and the first 3 used to find $b_0,b_1,b_2$. The data set used is the $x = [x_0, x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4] = [2,1,0,-1,0]$.

Note that for the first two equations $x(-1)$ and $x(-2)$ are implictly referenced, which are assumed to be zero for the causal modeling.

Comment: I assumed 3 b coefficients => q = 3. This might be the source of several problems I had. Thank you very much!

Comment: yes for the $a[k]$ coefficients $a_0 = 1$ by default, and thus only $p$ unknowns left, whereas for $b[k]$ coefficients $b_0$ is also an unknown and hence the number of unknown coefficients is $q+1$ (order plus one)